# Retrieving data from multiple tables using linq-to-sql

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql

We need to populate a bunch of controls on a form using Linq-to-SQL to retrieve the data. In order to get the data, we need to join several tables.

We have the following method:

First file:

```
public IEnumerable<object> getPRs()
{
    DataContext db = new DataContext();

    var prQuery = (from p in db.Invoice
                   join prd in db.InvoiceDetails on p.ID equals prd.ID
                   join pra in Accounting on p.ID equals pra.ID
                   where 1 == 1
                   orderby p.DownloadDate descending, p.PRNumber, Convert.ToInt32(p.Item)
                   select new
                          {
                              p.ID,
                              DownloadDate = Convert.ToString(p.DownloadDate),
                              p.PRNumber,
                              p.Item,
                              p.Material,
                              p.ClientMaterial,
                              p.Description,
                              p.Client,
                              p.Price,
                              p.UC,
                              prd.Supplier,
                              prd.Duns,
                              prd.RFQ,
                              prd.RFQDate,
                              prd.PO,
                              prd.PODate,
                              POValue = prd.Price * prd.Quantity,
                              pra.SO,
                              pra.SODate,
                              pra.SOValue,
                              pra.GR,
                              pra.GRDate,
                              pra.GI,
                              pra.GIDate,
                              pra.SInvoice,
                              pra.SInvoiceDate,
                              pra.CInvoice,
                              pra.CInvoiceDate,
                              p.isActive
                          }).ToList();
    return prQuery;
}
```

And we are calling the method like this on the second file:

```
IEnumerable<object> data = FirstFile.GetPRs();
PRNumberTextBox.Text = data.PRNumber;
```

The last line will give an error because we can't access the `PRNumber` member from the data object. In order to fill in all the text boxes, how can we call our function and add the necessary info?

Comment: `IEnumerable<object>` doesn't have `PRNumber` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning an anonymous type. I would recommend you create a model class to return your data:

```
public class PRModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string DownloadDate { get; set; }
    //etc... you can fill in the rest yourself
}
```

Then your query becomes something like this:

```
var prQuery = (from p in db.Invoice
               join prd in db.InvoiceDetails on p.ID equals prd.ID
               join pra in Accounting on p.ID equals pra.ID
               where 1 == 1
               orderby p.DownloadDate descending, p.PRNumber, Convert.ToInt32(p.Item)
               select new PRModel //<---This is the change here
               {
                   ID = p.ID,
                   DownloadDate = Convert.ToString(p.DownloadDate),
                   PRNumber = p.PRNumber,
                   //snipp
               }
```

And finally, your return type should now be `IEnumerable<PRModel>`. Also, as it's an enumeration (i.e. you may have 0, 1 or many items) you need to iterate through them:

```
IEnumerable<PRModel> data = FirstFile.GetPRs();
foreach(var pr in data)
{
    PRNumberTextBox.Text = pr.PRNumber;
}
```

---

**Edit:**

In this case, if you only want to return an individual invoice, it's even easier to do. Instead of doing this:

```
select new PRModel
{
    //lots of rows
}
```

You could simply do this:

```
select p
```

Which in turn makes your return type `IEnumerable<Invoice>`.

Comment: And if we have a lot of table (i.e 50 tables) do we need to make a class for every table? Or do we need to create a class for every query?

Comment: You already have a class for each table, your entity objects. You could return one of them if you like.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue**:
`PRNumber` is not a member of `IEnumerable<object>`. You need to iterate through `IEnumerable` to access each element.

**Solution:**
Second issue is that you're implicitly casting [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb397696.aspx) from *linq query* to an [*object*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kkx3h3c.aspx) so every element in a list you get from `getPRS()` will be an *object*. You can't access properties without casting to a specific type (as per @DavidG solution - new class/type for every aggregate function) or defining type at a runtime using [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dd264736.aspx).
The easiest fix will be to change return type to `IEnumerable<dynamic>`:

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> GetList()
        {
            var list = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4};
            return (from i in list
                   select new {
                       Integer = i,
                       Str = "Str" + i
                   }).ToList();
        }
```

and then:

```
var items = GetList();
Console.WriteLine(items.First().Integer); // prints "1" to console
```