# Retrieving data from 2 different SQL table to datagridview using Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have two tables in sql and i want to retrieve and fill a datagridview using 4 column from first table and 1 column from second table. My problem is, i am doing some ordering for the data from first table and i couldn't figure out how to join second table's column data. MeasResults table is the first table and Moulds is the second table.
Here is how i get MeasResults table data;

```
using (LinqDataClassesDataContext dataContext = new 
LinqDataClassesDataContext())
{
   var query = from x in dataContext.MeasResults
               where x.MoldID == cBMeasDBMID.SelectedValue.ToString()
               group x by x.MeasId into grp                           
               select grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.MeasId).First();

   var result = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.MeasId).Take(5);

   daGridLastMeas.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
   daGridLastMeas.Columns["MeasId"].DataPropertyName = "MeasId";
   daGridLastMeas.Columns["Date"].DataPropertyName = "Date";       
   daGridLastMeas.Columns["Plane"].DataPropertyName = "Plane";
   daGridLastMeas.Columns["Position"].DataPropertyName = "Postn";

   daGridLastMeas.DataSource = result;
}
```

And i tried to implement **join** function to get **HeatCnt** value from second table(Moulds).

```
using (LinqDataClassesDataContext dataContext = new 
LinqDataClassesDataContext())
{
   var query = from x in dataContext.MeasResults
               where x.MoldID == cBMeasDBMID.SelectedValue.ToString()
               join y in dataContext.Moulds on x.MoldID equals y.MID
               group x by x.MeasId into grp                           
               select grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.MeasId).First();

   var result = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.MeasId).Take(5);

   daGridLastMeas.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
   daGridLastMeas.Columns["MeasId"].DataPropertyName = "MeasId";
   daGridLastMeas.Columns["Date"].DataPropertyName = "Date";
   daGridLastMeas.Columns["Heat"].DataPropertyName = "HeatCnt";       
   daGridLastMeas.Columns["Plane"].DataPropertyName = "Plane";
   daGridLastMeas.Columns["Position"].DataPropertyName = "Postn";

   daGridLastMeas.DataSource = result;
}
```

I know my problem is at **select** part of the query but i couldn't find out how to add **y.HeatCnt** to select query.

How can i do this?

**NOTE**

I've already studied the following thread about joining two tables, but it is not quite in same arrangement with way of my code.

[Retrieving data from multiple tables using linq-to-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26487818/retrieving-data-from-multiple-tables-using-linq-to-sql)

> > EDIT

[image: Moulds_Table_SS]

[image: MeasResults_Table]

[image: Expected_Results] (Heat Column should display **0**)

Comment: can you please post table structure?

Comment: I added screenshots from tables. Is that ok?

Comment: What is the expected results set?

Comment: **Heat** column on the daGridLastMeas should show **0** when i select the Mould-ID **mld1**

Comment: can you give one row of your expected result?

Comment: ı added it to EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

I am bit confused about the data you want. But you can play arround with below solution and get your expected results.

```
var query = 
from i in dataContext.Moulds
    let p = dataContext.MeasResults.Where(p2 => i.MID == p2.MoldID).FirstOrDefault() 
    where i.MID == cBMeasDBMID.SelectedValue.ToString()
    orderby i.MeasId descending
    select new
    {
        MeasId = i.MID,
        Date = p.Date,
        Heat = i.Heat,
        Plane = p.Plane,
        Position = p.Position
};
```

Comment: This solution only returns one row. I need around 50.

Comment: Thats why I asked you expected output, you gave only 1 row. Please provide at least 5 rows which covers your expected output